# Correcting the map that proves countability of $N.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, modules

Here is the question that I am trying to understand its solution:

Let $M_i$ be the free $\mathbb Z$ module $\mathbb Z,$ and let $M$ be the direct product $\Pi_{i\in \mathbb Z^+}M_i.$ Each element of $M$ can be written uniquely in the form $(a_1, a_2,a_3, \dots )$ with $a_i \in \mathbb Z$ for all $i.$ Let $N$ be the submodule of $M$ consisting of all such tuples with only finitely many nonzero $a_i.$ Assume $M$ is a free $\mathbb Z$ module with basis $\mathcal B.$

$(a)$ Show that $N$ is countable.

**Here is a solution I found online:**

[image]

I think the map has typos in it, like, what is the $i$ beside $\phi_n$? why we are increasing the index of $i$ by $1$? why $i$ is starting from $0$ even though the first index of $a$ is $1$ in the definition of $M$?

Can someone help me correct all the typos in this map please?

Comment: for your first comment, I think the union was meant to be over $n$ where $n \in N^+.$

Comment: @pancini I think they want to show that $N$ is countable, not that $\Bbb N$ is countable.

Comment: @JonasLinssen thank you I thought I was having a stroke

Comment: @Secretly do I understand you correctly that you just want to show that $N=\bigoplus \limits_{n\in\Bbb N}\Bbb Z$ is countable? I am not sure why you assume $M=\prod\limits_{n\in\Bbb N}\Bbb Z$ is free, which seems to be false, but is irrelevant for what you want to prove…

Comment: i do not think the answer assumed this anywhere@JonasLinssen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically this is not an answer to the question, since it doesn‘t resolve the many difficulties the proposed solution has. But somehow I felt like proving the statement anyway.

Note that $N$ is in bijection to the set of functions
$$\operatorname{Map}_f(\Bbb N, \Bbb Z) = \{f:\Bbb N\rightarrow \Bbb Z\mid f(n)=0 \text{ for all but finitely many }n\}$$
of functions with finite support.

So we might just show the following more general statement: Given two countable sets $X,Y$ and a distinguished element $0\in Y$ the set $\operatorname{Map}_f(X,Y)$ of finitely supported functions is countable.

First note that for any finite set $F$ the set $\operatorname{Map}(F,Y)$ is countable.

Then note that for countable $X$ the set $\mathcal{P}_f(X)$ of finite subsets is countable. This is the special case $Y=\{0,1\}$ of what we want to show, but we better not argue like that. Luckily we can prove it by hand: Writing $\binom{X}{k}$ for the set of subsets of cardinality exactly $k$ we find that $$\mathcal{P}_f(X) = \bigcup\limits_{k\in\Bbb N_0} \binom{X}{k}$$
is countable as countable disjoint union of countable sets.

Finally the bijection
$$\operatorname{Map}_f(X,Y) \cong \bigcup\limits_{I\in\mathcal{P}_f(X)} \operatorname{Map}(I,Y\setminus\{0\})$$ implies our claim.